# Question of proof of archimedean property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, real-numbers, axioms

For every real number x there exists an integer $n$ such that $n>x$.

The book is using contradiction,

Suppose $x$ is a real number such that $n≤x$ for every $n$,that mean $x$ is the upper bound of natural number set.

then $M$ is an lowest upper bound of the set of integers and i guess that M is the integer.

$M-1<M$,meaning that $M-1$ must not the upper bound.

there will have $N>M-1$ ,because $M-1$ not the upper bound so there is a natural number N greater than it

$N+1>M$,that mean always have the integer greater than the lowest upper bound of the set of integers,contridcate with  natural number set having lowest upper bound.

the above only show that the natural number is unbounded by natural number,how is it related to natural number is also unbounded by the real number?

Also,i watched other proof on the website,it is curious that it derived $m+1>x$ in the conclusion. I mean if i take $x=8.5$,natural number set$=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$,then the lub of this set will be 6,and 5 is not upper bound of the this set,then m+1 will be 7,and 7 is not belong to set S but $(m+1>x)$ 7 is not greater than 8.5.

[image]

Comment: Quite a complicated proof for a statement so obvious that it is usually considered to be an axiom. The existence of such an integer is obvious by considering $n:=\lceil x \rceil + 1\ge x+1>x$ for non-negative $x$ and if $x$ is negative, $n=0$ already does the job.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to understand why the proof works

Comment: That is OK, but it uses several axioms each being less obvious than the statement that has to be proven. Ok then, what is unclear with this proof ?

Comment: First of all, the given proof seems not to consider the case that $x$ is negative. Although this case is obvious it should be mentioned. But in the case $x\ge 0$ , it is easy to see that $S$ cannot be empty.

Comment: Why m+1>x in the conclusion if I take x is 8.5,natural number set S={0,1,2,3,4,5,6}

Comment: S is the set of ALL naturals not exceeding $x$ , so in this case , $8$ is still in $S$. The argument is that $m+1>s$ , but $s$ is the supremum of $S$. Hence $m+1$ cannot belong to $S$, hence cannot be smaller than or equal to $x$.

Comment: Thanks I got it now, I misunderstood the definition of set S

Comment: the lub s is belong to natural number or real number?

Comment: S is discrete, hence the least upper bound is identical with the maximum member of $S$, in other words, the largest element of $S$.

Comment: I mean does the lub s is equal to greatest natural number of set S?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.